# Добавить картинку SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, java

Есть мой [проект](http://rghost.ru/download/58172805/8343a37da0ec0e921ff5ecb97a475ff3b95ec572/2activity.rar). Я хочу добавить картинку из Интернета на ListView, но никак не получается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, или исправьте, как это нужно сделать, чтобы картинка подгружалась из уже выделенной ссылки в этот лист вью.

Comment: @djbolya, Оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Comment: А что, собственно, исправлять? Где ваш код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)